# Position: 62 [See nested exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "is_volatile" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, quartz-scheduler

Hi i am new to quartz and postgres and whenever i try deploy the war in wildfly 8 server getting this error.

need your support on this.

```
quartz 1.6.0
struts-1.4.1
spring 1.1.4
hibernate-2.1.8

01:07:41,662 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 396) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "alerts-3.6.18.4 -test.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./alerts" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./alerts: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.quartz.SchedulerConfigException: Failure occured during job recovery. [See nested exception: org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't clean volatile data: ERROR: column \"is_volatile\" does not exist
  Position: 62 [See nested exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column \"is_volatile\" does not exist
  Position: 62]]
    Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.quartz.SchedulerConfigException: Failure occured during job recovery. [See nested exception: org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't clean volatile data: ERROR: column \"is_volatile\" does not exist
  Position: 62 [See nested exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column \"is_volatile\" does not exist
  Position: 62]]
    Caused by: org.quartz.SchedulerConfigException: Failure occured during job recovery. [See nested exception: org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't clean volatile data: ERROR: column \"is_volatile\" does not exist
  Position: 62 [See nested exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column \"is_volatile\" does not exist
  Position: 62]]
    Caused by: org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't clean volatile data: ERROR: column \"is_volatile\" does not exist
  Position: 62 [See nested exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column \"is_volatile\" does not exist
  Position: 62]
    Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column \"is_volatile\" does not exist
  Position: 62"}}
```

Comment: Please show the complete error message.

Comment: Hi jjanes , pls find the updated comment and quartz 1.8.6 also im getting this error and i having the column name that i checked in my DB also

Comment: It looks like some table in PostgreSQL doesn't have the structure that quartz expects it to.  Maybe the table was created by a prior version of quartz, and did not get migrated correctly?  If you look in the db server's log file, there should be a better error message that at least gives you the table name.

Comment: thanks for the info jjanes let me have a look

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
```

in your application.properties file.